# How to have Dapper iterate a stored procedure for inserts?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dapper

I have the following Dapper command to insert values into a table using a stored procedure.

```
sqlConnection.Execute(
       "sp_LocationTypes_Insert"
       , parameters
       , commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure
       );
```

where the parameters are created using

```
var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("@updated", dbType: DbType.DateTime, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
parameters.Add("@description", locationType.description);
```

In addition, the SP needs to be executed multiple times, once for each LocationType object in a list. I could put the list in a loop and call the Execute command for each instance. However, is there a way to have Dapper iterate the list of objects and execute the SP? I do not want to put the T-SQL as a string.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent a while in the Dapper Source and have seen nothing in regards to dapper iterating internally like you are asking.  For this question i referenced Dapper's unit tests and i can find no example of dapper attempting to do this.  With this being said, i would assume it does not.

Here is the link to their general unit tests, if you browse up a level they have it organized into other sections.

https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper.Tests/Tests.cs

I consider this to be my comprehensive guide on 'how to use' dapper.